# Linq max of 2 columns of datagridvieuw with empty cells

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

```
double MaxSales = 0;

MaxSales = dgvSales.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                   .Where(z => z.Cells["Jaar"].Value.ToString() == lblSelectedJaar.Text)
                   .Where(o => o.Cells["vHigh"].Value != DBNull.Value)
                   .Where(oo => oo.Cells["VLow"].Value != DBNull.Value)
                   .Max(s => Convert.ToDouble(s.Cells["VLow"].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(s.Cells["vHigh"].Value));
```

If there is a empty cell on one of the columns, then it will not return  the highest value.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to treat `DBNull.Value` as 0:

```
double MaxSales = dgvSales.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(z => z.Cells["Jaar"].Value.ToString() == lblSelectedJaar.Text)
    .Select(o => (o.Cells["vHigh"].Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(s.Cells["vHigh"])) 
               + (o.Cells["VLow"].Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(s.Cells["VLow"])))
    .Max();
```

Comment: Thanks Tim and yes i like to treat the empty cell as 0 but now i get an error. System.InvalidCastException in mscorlib.dll (can not an object of the type System.windows.Forms.Datagridvieuw TextboxCell convert to the type SystemIConvertible

Comment: @RonaldRoenhorst: what error?